# Message contextual filtering

Tags: views, blocks, message-subscribe

I have been trying out the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. I am using it to send notifications to users' profiles whenever a node of a certain content type is added (a simple `hook_node_insert()` in combination with `Message::create()`). These notifications are displayed in a view block on the user's profile page (this block is an alteration of the base [Message View](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180203). Let's say these are nodes whose content type is *Event*, and each of these nodes has a taxonomy term reference field called *Event type* (e.g. Sports, Conference, Concert, etc.).

Let's say that a user only wants to be notified about events for which the value of the *Event type* field is *Concert*. In the user form, I have provided a field which contains checkboxes for all of the different event types (its a list of all of the terms that come from the *Event type* vocabulary). Whenever a user visits their profile page, they should only see notifications for the event types they've selected.

I haven't been able to find a solution for how to implement this either at message creation or through some sort of view block hook. I am now trying to do it through Views filters/relationships.

To make the long story short, my view block contains a list of Message type entities, each with an *event_type* field that references a single taxonomy term. Every user entity on the page has a *event_notification_preferences* field which is basically an array of taxonomy terms selected by the user.

What I would like to do can be explained through an example. Let's say the view contains three messages, each with a different *event_type* field (Sports, Conference, Concert). The currently logged in user's *event_notification_preferences* array contains only one reference (to the Concert term).

How can I filter the view to display only those messages whose *event_type* field is relevant (i.e., it has a corresponding match in the event_notification_preferences array, in this case *Concert*)? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps someone - I solved the issue by creating a view block of Messages, then I:

- Added a relationship with the Taxonomy term referenced from the *event_type* field.
- Added a relationship with the User using the *event_notification_preferences* field.
- Added a contextual filter for **User: User ID** and got the default
  value from the currently logged in user.